# iOS/Xcode enable On Demand Resources for Frameworks in project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bundle, on-demand-resources

Has anyone built a project that has `Enable On Demand Resources` set to `YES` for frameworks linked to the project. Most of the catalog assets in the app I'm working on are kept and brought into the project in frameworks and I get build error `Target '<Framework/Bundle>Name' has on-demand resources enabled (ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES = YES), but it is not supported for framework target types.` and unable to compile the project.